# Converting string to date and storing it in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have a String stating the date as "2012-12-31" how can I convert it into date format using java and store it MySQL database where the type in MySQL is of date type.

Comment: `2012-12-31` is already date format or what you mean ?

Comment: What are your table formats?  What have you tried?

Comment: If you want to convert String to Date object:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows

```
String string = "2012-12-31"; 

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(string);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()); // convert java.util.date to java.sql.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String string = "2012-12-31"; //You have like this now

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date date = formatter.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```